# How to inherit parent div when centering text inside?

Tags: html, css

I have a div mission-statement which should be the entire viewable browser width and height

```
<div id="mission-statement">
    <video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="{{ url_for('static',filename='images/cclc-background-image.png') }}" id="bgvid">
        <source src="{{ url_for('static',filename='videos/cclc-background-video.mov') }}" type="video/webm">
    </video>
    <div id="mission-statement-text">
    <h1>Map-Based Operations Management for Enterprise</h1>
    </div>
</div>

#mission-statement{
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    height: 100vh;
    width:100vw;
}
```

This part does show up as white with a black border

```
#mission-statement h1{
    color: white;
    text-shadow: -3px 0 black, 0 3px black, 3px 0 black, 0 -3px black;

}
```

This is the part that doesn't seem to work

```
#mission-statement-text{
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Its basically 50% of the way down the entire webpage. I want it 50% of the way down the div (centered vertically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `position: absolute` if that text is supposed to appear above/inside the parent.

```css
#mission-statement {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#mission-statement h1 {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: -3px 0 black, 0 3px black, 3px 0 black, 0 -3px black;
}

#mission-statement-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="mission-statement">
  <video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="{{ url_for('static',filename='images/cclc-background-image.png') }}" id="bgvid">
        <source src="{{ url_for('static',filename='videos/cclc-background-video.mov') }}" type="video/webm">
    </video>
  <div id="mission-statement-text">
    <h1>Map-Based Operations Management for Enterprise</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: awesome. For some reason when I try and center the text horizontally, by adding transform:translateX(-50%); it doesn't think this is applicable. Is there something about the position: absolute that would prevent other things like this from working?

Comment: Just add `width: 100%` and `text-align: center`.  (which I did in my edited version). Absolute position works more reliable when there is are width and/or height settings

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on flexbox. You can center text using something like

```
.align-center {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
```

More detailed:
https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Comment: hmm that seems to move the text to the side of the div for some reason

Comment: Could you paste a screenshot how it should look like? I can't really imagine what you want to achieve exactly..